# Counting process instances with grep & wc

Tags: bash, grep, ps, wc

I am trying to count process instances using the following command:

```
$ ps -ef | grep "test.sh" | egrep -v "grep|vi|more|pg" | wc -l
1
```

Which works perfectly on the command line, but in the script when I assign the output to a variable:

```
script_instances=`ps -ef | grep "test.sh" | egrep -v "grep|vi|more|pg" | wc -l`
echo $script_instances
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

It increments by 1, which I don't understand why it's happening.

If I just put following command in script it prints correctly

`ps -ef | grep "test.sh" | egrep -v "grep"`

Output:

`root     14243 12162  0 19:12 pts/1    00:00:00 sh test.sh`

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: If you remove the `wc -l` and look at the contents of `script_instances`, what do you see?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Updated my Question

Comment: Ideally, **don't use `ps | grep` at all**. The `pgrep` command will do the above, but also innately avoid matching itself.

Comment: (And if your goal is to ensure that there's only one instance of a script, the most reliable way to do that is with a lockfile; that way you don't have a problem if someone's opening a file in an editor you didn't know about and blacklist, or if there's another script by the same name, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Following fixed the issue `grep -cw "test.sh"`

```
script_instances=`ps -ef | grep -cw "test.sh" | egrep -v "grep|vi|more|pg" | wc -l`
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `grep foo | grep -v grep`, that gets processed by `grep` when the shell executes `grep`, instead use `[ ]` to get the pattern of your script name.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -c '[te]st.sh'

-c counts the number of matches
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `[t]est.sh`? `[te]st.sh` only matches `tst.sh` or `est.sh` (plus any variants of the above with the `.` replaced with another character, since it's a wildcard in regex notation).

Comment: ...actually, `test[.]sh` would be a better place to be -- that way you stop the `.` from being treated as a wildcard, *and* prevent the process from matching itself.